# How should I fetch firebase data in my app

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native

Hey there hope your fine I want to develope my first react native app so I need to get data from firebase but the problem my data look like that 
`{id : {name:"" , image:""}}` with deferent id for every line I mean after getting data and store it in a state.

So how can I take every line and put it in a flat list for exemple ? 
this is my real result:

```
{001: {image: "http://itgsmgroup.com/dev/foo/Activites-socio-culturelles.png", name: "Activités socioculturels"}
002: {image: "http://itgsmgroup.com/dev/foo/Accompagnement-juridique.png", name: "Accopagnement juridique"}
003: {image: "http://itgsmgroup.com/dev/foo/Sante.png", name: "santé"}
004: {image: "http://itgsmgroup.com/dev/foo/Formation.png", name: "formation et inseriton"}
005: {image: "", name: "information"}}
and this how i get data 
getData() {
        firebase.database().ref('categories/').on('value', (snapshot) => {
            console.log(snapshot.val());
            this.setState({
                data: snapshot.val()
            });    
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this snack that i made for a working sample with your question on [expo.io snack](https://snack.expo.io/SJ1Qe1J04).

```
    export default class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(props){
       super(props)
       /**
       * This next line is used to convert the object that you receive from Firebase to an Array 
       * which is what a FlatList expects as data
       */
      var tempListData = Object.entries(rawData).map(([key, value]) => value) 
      this.state = {
      listData: tempListData
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //Normally this lifecycle method is where you would dispatch a call to firebase but for 
    //demostration purposes am using static data defined above.
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          style={{flex: 1, padding: 10}}
          data={this.state.listData}
          renderItem={({item})=>(<View style={{height: 40}}><Text>{item.name}</Text></View>)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

In summary you will need to convert the json object that you get from Firebase to an Array that you can pass to Flatlist.

Comment: it should look like that ? firebase.database().ref('categories/').on('value', (snapshot) => {
            console.log(snapshot.val());
            const tempListData = Object.entries(snapshot.val()).map(([key, value]) => value);
            this.setState({
                data: tempListData
            });    
        });